# Scaffolding for a widget dashboard

Tags: css, widget

I am working on a project that has a dashboard of widgets, which looks like a prettier version of iGoogle. Currently, each `.widget` is essentially a bootstrap "column" with widths 4, 8 and 12 (we have a 12 column layout). But that simply doesn't work as it leaves empty spaces and causes unpredictable line breaks (especially when widgets on the left are longer than widgets on the right):

[image: Normal layout]
[image: Broken layout]

Can someone please provide the right widget style? Thanks!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/speljn9WYZ2r7g6NnnLD?p=preview

Comment: If you can create a demo of your code, we can debug the issue.http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Unfortunately, all my code is on a corporate network that I cannot readily share. But I've created a plunker that uses the bootstrap classes and illustrates my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, this is the widget style I ended up using:

```
.widget {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c2c0c5;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: "ProxReg", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-table;

  &.widget-1 {
    width: calc(33.3333333% - 20px);
  }

  &.widget-2 {
    width: calc(66.6666666% - 20px);
  }

  &.widget-3 {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-small) {
    &.widget-1,
    &.widget-2,
    &.widget-3 {
      width: calc(100% - 20px);
    }
  }
}
```